# Accessing data separately from multiple tables in single view in blade template laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have three different tables: `persons`, `students` and `teachers`. I was able to join three tables and get data as follows:

```
public function viewProduct()
{
    $persons = Person::with(['students','teachers'])->get();
    return view('master.viewPeoples', compact('persons'));
}
```

I want to access data in my blade. How can I get data of students and teachers table in my blade template? I have the columns `rollNum`, `year`, and `semester` in the `students` table and the columns `salary` and `courses` in the `teachers` table.

The following source code returns data from the `person` table only.

```
@foreach($persons as $person)
    {{ $person->name }}
    {{ $person->universityNum }}
    {{ $person->rollNum  }}        //returns blank
    {{ $person->year }}            //returns blank
    ...         
@endforeach
```

I get all data for students and teachers when I do this:

```
@foreach($persons as $person)
    {{ $person->students }}
    {{ $person->teachers }}
@endforeach
```

But I want to access data of each column of students and teachers table separately like`$students->rollNum`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
@foreach($persons as $person)
   {{ $person->name }}

   @foreach($person->students as $student)
      {{ $student->rollNum }}
      {{ $student->year }}
   @endforeach

  // Do same for teachers here
@endforeach
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@foreach($persons as $person)
    {{ $person->students->rollNum }}
    {{ $person->teachers->rollNum }}
@endforeach
```

or

```
@foreach($persons as $person)
    {{ $person->students_rollNum }}
    {{ $person->teachers_rollNum }}
@endforeach
```